# Python - Getting N elements which occur once from a list by keeping indices of got elements

Tags: python

I have two long lists; `f` and `e`. Values of `f` corresponds to values of `e` at same index. For instance;

```
f = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e", ...]
e = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", ...]
```

I want to create a list, which will involve `n` elements from `f`, and a list which will involve the corresponds of those `n` elements from `e`. So basically the indexes of got elements from `f` will be the same with got elements from `e`.

```
f_sub = ["b", ...]
e_sub = ["B", ...]
```

Afterwards, I want to remove these `n` elements from the list `f`, and its corresponds from the list `e`, by keeping the order of `f` with its corresponds to `e`.

```
f_new = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e", ...]
e_new = ["A", "C", "D", "E", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", ...]
```

I have done it, but it cost so expensive for me, the code runs very slowly.

```
import codecs, random, time

from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import dropwhile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Importing English corpus ..."
    f = codecs.open("../corpus/corpus.en", encoding = "utf-8").readlines()
    init_f = f

    print "Importing Turkish corpus ..."
    e = codecs.open("../corpus/corpus.tr", encoding = "utf-8").readlines()


    print "Creating dictionary ..."
    trans = defaultdict()
    for d in range(len(f)):
        trans[f[d]] = e[d]

    print "Calculating occurences in corpus ..."
    cnt = Counter(f)

    print "Creating test data ..."
    f_test = open("../dataset/test.en", "w")
    e_test = open("../dataset/test.tr", "w")
    cntr = 0
    for a in range(len(f)):
        if cnt[f[a]] == 1:
            print str(cntr+1) + " : 5000"
            f_test.write(f[a].encode("utf-8"))
            e_test.write(e[a].encode("utf-8"))
            f.remove(f[a])
                        e.remove(e[a])
            cnt[f[a]] = 0
            cntr += 1
            if cntr == 5000:
                break
    f_test.close()
    e_test.close()

    print "Creating development data ..."
        f_dev = open("../dataset/dev.en", "w")
        e_dev = open("../dataset/dev.tr", "w")
    cntr = 0
        for b in range(len(f)):
        if cnt[f[b]] == 1:
            print str(cntr+1) + " : 5000"
                    f_dev.write(f[b].encode("utf-8"))
                    e_dev.write(e[b].encode("utf-8"))
            f.remove(f[b])
                        e.remove(e[b])
            cnt[f[b]] = 0
            cntr += 1
            if cntr == 5000:
                break
        f_dev.close()
        e_dev.close()

    print "Creating train data ..."
        f_train = open("../dataset/train.en", "w")
        e_train = open("../dataset/train.tr", "w")
        for c in range(len(f)):
        print str(c+1) + " : " + str(len(f))
                f_train.write(f[c].encode("utf-8"))
                e_train.write(e[c].encode("utf-8"))
        f_train.close()
        e_train.close()
```

What can be a very fast way to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the code you used?

Comment: What about duplicates? Let's say `f_sub` contains single `'a'` instead of `'b'` what would be the expected result?

Comment: Please share your code before asking for efficiency issues

Comment: My code is very huge.

Comment: create a sandbox case

Comment: Copying big lists can be expensive. Can you modify your original list? If so and as you know the indexes you can use slice assignment: `e[start:stop] = []; f[start:stop] = []`. Or create one copy `e_new(e); e_new[start:stop] = []; ...`